# Centering AIR application with fullscreen

Tags: air, adobe, fullscreen, centering

I have a application developed in AIR /AS 3.0..
i want to run the application in full screen with all the content centered in the window.
i tried to do fullscreen with

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE
```

but turned out all my components dont get centered on the screen as needed(when in full screen) and they get cutoff or they are off screen.
Basically the application was developed in lower resolution about 1024x768...but now it needs to run full screen.Also the application loads various modules at runtime they also dont appear to be centered in fullscreen.When the application comes out of fullscreen it also shows scrollbars for the application window..

Edit :Code added :

```
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
          layout="absolute" width="1024" height="768">

     <Application:ApplicationStartContainer id="aps" width="100%" height="100%">

               <mx:ModuleLoader id="moduleLoader"/>    

     </Application:ApplicationStartContainer>            

</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

On start, the Application goes fullscreen,and the module loader loads modules/swfs
that are of size 1024*768 ,but currently all loaded modules get aligned to 
x=0 and y=0.

Any ideas?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

layout all of your display objects in a display object container - as children of a new sprite, and listen for a full screen event to center the display object container.

```
stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, fullScreenEventHandler);

//assuming the registration point of 'container' is top-left
function fullScreenEventHandler(evt:FullScreenEvent):void
     {
     container.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - container.width / 2;
     container.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - container.height / 2;
     }
```

note that the full screen event is dispatched when both entering and leaving full screen mode.

Comment: basically the container has a module loader that loads various modules..i want the loaded modules to be in center of the application.whenever the screen goes fullscreen the module loader sticks to the topleft(x=0 and y=0) of the screen..instead of centering in screen.modules have same size as that of container..1024 by 768

Comment: right, so center your module loader instead of a container using the same approach.  moduleLoader.x = stage.stageWidth / - moduleLoader.width / 2;, etc.